# Populating a dynamic webpage based on another webpage's data using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a file index.php where a user enters his data (name, age, state, country) and then clicks on submit button which will redirect him to about.php and in about.php his information is displayed. How to achieve that using jquery. I am new to web development, here is my code :
index.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
        <input type="text" id = "name" >
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <input type="text" id = "age" >
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <input type="text" id = "state" >
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <input type="text" id = "country" >
</div>
<a href="about.php">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block col-md-2" id = "submit">Submit</button>
</a>
```

about.php

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<table class="table table-bordered" id = "about-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

script.js(included in both about.php and index.php)

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
var name = $("#name").val()
var age = $("#age").val()
var state = $("#state").val()
var country = $("#country").val()

var newRow = $("<tr>");
var cols = "";
cols += '<td>' + name +'</td>';
cols += '<td>' + age + '</td>';
cols += '<td>' + state + '</td>';
cols += '<td>' + country + '</td>';
newRow.append(cols);
$("#about-table").append(newRow);
});
```

Comment: Please do some basic research/learning about how to handle forms with PHP

Comment: you can't carry data over from page to page on the client side without a) parsing a url that you previously put data in, b) use cookies or c) use local or session storage

Comment: How to pass data from index.php to about.php? I am getting the data in script.js now how to pass this data to populate index.php. Could you please help.

Comment: Look some information up about form handling, specifically about `$_POST`, store data in a db, and print it out on your `about.php`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using web storage([localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)).

> **Beaware that localStorage stores data for only one session!**

I've created two *.html files - one called **'page1.html'** and other **'page2.html'**.

**page1.html** consists of input form and seting values to web storage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name..." />
    <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="Your age..." />
    <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State..." />
    <input type="text" id="country" placeholder="Country..." />
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    ( function() {

        var name, age, state, country;

        //  Get & set data on submit
        $('form').on('submit', function(e) {

            //  prevent submition
            e.preventDefault();

            //  set var values
            name = $('#name').val(),
            age = $('#age').val(),
            state = $('#state').val(),
            country = $('#country').val()

            if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
                //  Store values to web storage
                window.localStorage.setItem('name', name);
                window.localStorage.setItem('age', age);
                window.localStorage.setItem('state', state);
                window.localStorage.setItem('country', country);
            } else {
                //  web storage not supported
            }

            //  redirect to page2.html
            window.location.replace('page2.html');

        });

    })();
</script>
```

**page2.html** consists of table in which to show data and geting values from web storage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="name"></td>
        <td id="age"></td>
        <td id="state"></td>
        <td id="country"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    ( function() {

        //  table columns
        var $name = $('#name'),
            $age = $('#age'),
            $state = $('#state'),
            $country = $('#country');

        //  get & set values from web storage
        $name.text(window.localStorage.getItem('name'));
        $age.text(window.localStorage.getItem('age'));
        $state.text(window.localStorage.getItem('state'));
        $country.text(window.localStorage.getItem('country'));

    })();
</script>
```

But you should use php instead(to insert & get data etc).